# Including a single value when grouping in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to run a query on how productive a user has been, based on the "Amount" column.  In addition, I need to know the date/time of the first Amount that was entered.

Existing Records:

```
UserID      Amount        DateTime
1           1             09/25/2015 08:00:01
1           2             09/25/2015 08:31:11
1           3             09/25/2015 09:02:22
2           2             09/25/2015 09:57:42
3           1             09/25/2015 10:11:12
3           4             09/25/2015 11:10:09
4           1             09/25/2015 12:15:15
4           5             09/25/2015 12:22:56
5           2             09/25/2015 12:57:32
```

Expected Output

```
UserID        TotalAmount   FirstDateTime
1             6             09/25/2015 08:00:01
2             2             09/25/2015 09:57:42
3             5             09/25/2015 10:11:12
4             6             09/25/2015 12:15:15
5             2             09/25/2015 12:57:32
```

I can get the first two columns by doing

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Amount) As TotalAmount FROM tblAmounts GROUP BY UserID
```

But I am having trouble figuring out what I need to do in order to include that third column.

Comment: Just note that the the desired result doesn't match your word problem (for example, UserID 2's datetime value seems to have been derived from MAX, not MIN).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add another aggregate function for the third value.

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Amount) As TotalAmount, min(DateTime) as FirstDateTime  FROM tblAmounts GROUP BY UserID
```